# .css() Jquery method makes the entire document not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('#left-div').css("background-color": "white", "color": "black");
```

If I put that line in the JavaScript file I'm working in the entire file stops working, however if I comment it out or change it to anything other than .css it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you have more than one css feature you have to put it in `{` and `}`

Comment: please check the documentation of any framework you're using before asking questions in forums, boards, or SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is off, try this;

```
$('#left-div').css({
    "background-color": "white",
    "color": "black"
})
```

(note the curly brackets)

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is invalid!

try this way:

```
$('#left-div').css({"background-color": "white", "color": "black"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that method in that way

http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$('#left-div').css( { "background-color": "white", "color": "black" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this**

```
$('#left-div').css({
   'background-color' : 'white',
   color : 'black'
});
```